# 'ASAP' & 'UBUNTU 'google font suddenly disformed

Tags: fonts, google-font-api, text-rendering

We've been using the ASAP font in our web application for the past years without a problem. Suddenly we started noticing deformities using the 'ASAP' google font. They only occured when the font was used to render < 16px font-size. Same issues arised with the 'Ubuntu' font.

Does anyone have any idea what is causing these issues?

We've noticed these issues on: IE11, lastest Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Safari, on the OS's Win10, MacOS.

[image: example-1]
[image: example-2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by manually downloading the fonts and using them in our project.

Answer (score 2):

I have exactly the same problem with these fonts. A few days ago it looked good. I tried almost everything to fix it. Unfortunately, the only method that works for this moment is to change the font to something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I can use `google-webfonts-helper` to automate my installing of fonts locally. And sure enough, with this setup, my local copy of Ubuntu Regular is now being detected.

```
Install fonts via Google Fonts instead of Cask
```